# Is it possible to get number of statements inside an action or determine if it has empty body?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, action, func

Let's say we have this code :

```
Action<int> gf = k => { };
Action<int> gfa = k => { k++; };
```

How I can determine that `gf` has no body or statements ?
Is it possible to get number of statements inside a `Action` ?

Something similar to `GetNumberOfStatements(gf)` which should `return 0`.
Or maybe HasEmptyBody(gf) which should `return true`;

Comment: It's a *lot* easier if your lambda is an expression instead of a delegate (which can be compiled to a delegate later) - is that a possibility?

Comment: For what purpose do you want to do this?

Comment: @vcsjones Sorry I can't use expression for this.

Comment: @MattWilko I'm passing this as a parameter to another method which latter will call this action.

Comment: Seems like a job for Roslyn.

Comment: This is really a rather naive way of doing this, but for your exact case it should work: https://gist.github.com/vcsjones/5310717

Comment: nice one @vcsjones, interesting approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's a little bit iffy, but you could inspect the IL of the method-body and check if it is empty or consists entirely of [Nops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.nop.aspx) (apart from the Ret at the end of course).

Obviously, you will get false-positives here if the compiler of the programming language that the method was written in has compiled away operations without any impact. But I assume you're primarily interested in the `(arg1, arg2, ... ) => { }` C# case, for which this should work ok.

```
public static bool IsEmpty(this Delegate del)
{
    // Null arg-checking omitted.

    short nop = System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Nop.Value;

    var ilArray = del.Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();

    return ilArray.Take(ilArray.Length - 1).All(b => b == nop);
}
```

Comment: Acording to vcsjones is your code safe with `il[0] == OpCodes.Ret.Value` ? https://gist.github.com/vcsjones/5310717

Comment: Yes, it is. Although, you've given me the idea to replace my 0 with OpCodes.Nop.Value. Thanks!

Comment: @Mahdi this is more or less the same as my approach, just with an elegant explanation attached (which is why I voted it up). His just doesn't bother to check the last op at all since it pretty much has to be a `ret`. Mine just ensures that every instruction is nop and checks that the last one is ret.

Comment: @vcsjones Ahh right. Thank you both for your brilliant answers :)

Comment: @vcsjones: Thanks for your edit! It was from looking at your link that I remembered the framework already provides codes for each instruction; but I didn't bother re-testing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Delegates in .Net are little more than function pointers.  Just like you can't tell how many C# statements are in a .Net method, you can't tell how many statements are in a .Net delegate.  In part because the method isn't necessarily coded in C# or any other language which has a notion of statements.  It could be written directly in IL which is opcode based

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Decided to touch this up a little bit while I wait for my build server to reboot...

I actually have something lying around my "utility library" that sorta-kinda-maybe might help you - there's a lot of room for improvement here, naturally - this was never meant for "production use":

```
public static void DumpMethod(Delegate method)
{
    var mb = method.Method.GetMethodBody();
    var il = mb.GetILAsByteArray();
    var opCodes = typeof(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes)
        .GetFields()
        .Select(fi => (System.Reflection.Emit.OpCode)fi.GetValue(null));
    var mappedIL = il.Select(op => opCodes.FirstOrDefault(opCode => opCode.Value == op));
    var ilWalker = mappedIL.GetEnumerator();
    while(ilWalker.MoveNext())
    {
        var mappedOp = ilWalker.Current;
        if(mappedOp.OperandType != System.Reflection.Emit.OperandType.InlineNone)
        {
            var byteCount = 0;
            long operand = 0;
            switch(mappedOp.OperandType)
            {
                case System.Reflection.Emit.OperandType.InlineI:
                case System.Reflection.Emit.OperandType.InlineBrTarget:
                case System.Reflection.Emit.OperandType.InlineMethod:                
                case System.Reflection.Emit.OperandType.InlineField:
                case System.Reflection.Emit.OperandType.InlineSig:
                case System.Reflection.Emit.OperandType.InlineString:
                case System.Reflection.Emit.OperandType.InlineType:
                case System.Reflection.Emit.OperandType.InlineSwitch:
                    byteCount = 4;
                    break;
                case System.Reflection.Emit.OperandType.InlineI8:
                case System.Reflection.Emit.OperandType.InlineR:
                    byteCount = 8;
                    break;
            }
            for(int i=0; i < byteCount; i++)
            {
                ilWalker.MoveNext();
                operand |= ((long)ilWalker.Current.Value) << (8 * i);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", mappedOp.Name, operand);                    
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", mappedOp.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Test Rig:

```
Func<int,int> addOne = i => i + 1;
DumpMethod(addOne);
Console.WriteLine();
Func<int,string> stuff = i =>
{
    var m = 10312;      
    var j = i + m;
    var k = j * j + i;
    var asStr = k.ToString();
    return asStr;
};
DumpMethod(stuff);
```

Output:

```
ldarg.0
ldc.i4.1
add
ret

ldc.i4 10312
stloc.0
ldarg.0
ldloc.0
add
stloc.1
ldloc.1
ldloc.1
mul
ldarg.0
add
stloc.2
ldloca.s 0
ldarg.0
call 167772167
stloc.3
ldloc.3
ret
```